# Is there any way to access a file of bluestack without using any file explorer?

Tags: android, windows, desktop

Is there any way to access a file from bluestack without using any file explorer?

I have tried a lot but didn't get any solution, it seems compulsory to use the explorer?

Does anyone know how to use bluestacks media file (video, photos, etc) without using explorer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You have to compulsory use explorer, either you can do it like this

***Using Windows Registry***

**Caution**: *The following section involves in editing values in the Windows Registry. The Windows Registry contains values and keys that are critical to the Operating System. Modify the Windows Registry very carefully as any undesired modification may cause your system to malfunction.*

1. Decide on which directory to give access in BlueStacks. You can either choose an entire hard drive, or a particular folder of your choice.
2. Access the Windows Registry by going to *Start* -> *Run*, type in `regedit` and hit Enter. This opens up the Registry Editor.
3. Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\BlueStacks\Guests\Android\FileSystem`. Inside this folder you’ll find some predefined numeric keys and values (starting with `0`). Create a new key here by right-clicking on *FileSystem* and select *New* -> *Key* and rename it by the number following the previous key. Update: The newer versions of BlueStacks depends on a different Registry Key. For the newer version, go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\BlueStacks\Guests\Android\ SharedFolder. Create a new key here and rename it to the number following the previous key.
4. Inside the newly created key, right-click on the space on the right side and create a new String called “Name” by selecting New >> String. Double-click on it and enter a value. The value is the name of the folder as seen inside BlueStacks. Update: In the newer versions, additionally create a new DWORD Value by right-clicking on the blank space and selecting New >> DWORD (32 Bit) Value and rename it as Writable. Right-click on this newly created value and click Modify. Set the Value data field as 1 and select the base as Hexadecimal.
5. Create another String called “Path” and assign a value of the full path of the directory you want to include inside BlueStacks. For example, if you want to access the Downloads folder of D drive inside BlueStacks, set the path value as “D:\Downloads” (without quotes, of course). You can include as many directories as you like by creating new keys for each of the folders. Keep the keys sequential in number.
6. Restart your computer for the changes to take effect.

you can access your photos videos from particular drive